# How to define a state as object in react using hooks

Tags: reactjs

I ma working on a React project, I am trying to define an a state to a button. But state is not applying to a button can you please correct me

This is my code

This is App.js

`````
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "antd"
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [buttonOne, setButtonOne] = useState("red")

  const [buttonTwo, setButtonTwo] = useState({
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: "black",
    border: "red"
  })


  return (
    <div>
      <Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonOne, border: buttonOne}} className="one" type="primary">First</Button>
      <Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonTwo, color: buttonTwo, border: buttonTwo}} className="two" type="primary">Second</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div>
   <Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonOne, border: buttonOne}} className="one" type="primary">First</Button>
   <Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonTwo.backgroundColor, color: buttonTwo.color, border: buttonTwo.border}} className="two" type="primary">Second</Button>
</div>
```

Since your state is object, you need to go inner fields like -

**`buttonTwo.border`** or **`buttonTwo['color']`**

Example

```
<Button style={{backgroundColor: buttonTwo.backgroundColor, color: buttonTwo['color'], border: buttonTwo.border}} className="two" type="primary">Second</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the second button you would need to access the object's properties.

`backgroundColor: buttonTwo.backgroundColor`

`color: buttonTwo.color`

`border: buttonTwo.border`